# How to pass additional parameter in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab-ci, octopus-deploy

I want to design a pipeline for executing a program that can have multiple configurations by argument. Developer is not interested to have each argument as a variable and they want to have the option to be able to add multiple variables by using pipeline. we are using bash and our development using gitlab-ci and we are using octopus for uat env deployment.

example:

```bash
spark2-submit \
--master $MASTER \
--name $NAME \
--queue $QUEUE \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=12
```

As you can see in the above example, I want to have flexibility in adding more "--conf" parameters.

should I have a dummy parameter and then add it to the end of this command?

for example:

```bash
spark2-submit \
--master $MASTER \
--name $NAME \
--queue $QUEUE \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=12 \
$additional_param
```

I am using Gitlab for my code repo and Octopus for my CICD. I am using bash for deployment. I am looking for a flexible option that I can use the full feature of the Octopus variable option and gitlab. what is your recommendation? do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Lists of arguments should be stored in arrays.

Comment: "add multiple variables by using pipeline" -- from the perspective of this shell script, what does that look like?

Comment: @glennjackman, note that "pipeline" is a term of art in CI, so there's not much reason to believe this is necessarily referring to _shell_ pipelines.

Comment: Right, but how will the shell script acquire these additional conf variables? From command line parameters? From the environment?

Comment: @Amir, ...you'll likely get better responses here if you can form it into a question that requires only bash knowledge, and not octopus knowledge; in practice, that means trying to assemble a question that folks who don't know how octopus handles variables can answer.

Comment: If it's just a direct mapping to environment variables, I might try to build a translation layer that looks for variables starting with `conf__*` and then translates `conf__spark_shuffle_service_enabled=true` to `--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true`; that's not a difficult thing to implement.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy currently we are using an array but I was thinking is there any other option.

Comment: Show _how_ you're using arrays and why that's a problem for you. The other options, generally speaking, are worse -- they can look like they work for simple cases, but when you get into values with whitespace they turn out to be buggy. So instead of just asking what your other options are, show what you're doing now in enough detail to make it clear why it's cumbersome so we can focus on fixing whatever pain point led you to ask this question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: we are using array in an almost similar way, but the idea of having a translation layer was a brilliant idea. when we are using parameter we are suffering when there is a white space, specially I have some value which they are in json format. so at the moment I am just decode them in base64. but not sure is it a good idea or there is other way as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Charles is hinting at with "Lists of arguments should be stored in arrays":

```bash
spark2_opts=(
    --master "$MASTER"
    --name "$NAME"
    --queue "$QUEUE"
    --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=12 
)

# add additional options, through some mechanism such as the environment:
if [[ -n "$SOME_ENV_VAR" ]]; then
    spark2_opts+=( --conf "$SOME_ENV_VAR" )
fi

# and execute
spark2-submit "${spark2_opts[@]}"
```

bash array definitions can contain arbitrary whitespace, including newlines,
so format for readability

Comment: Or maybe something more involved, iterating over `for var_name in "${!conf__@}"; do key=${var_name#conf__}; key=${key//_/.}; value=${!var_name}; spark2_opts+=( --conf "$key=$value" ); done`, f/e.

Comment: perhaps this should be community wiki...

Comment: _shrug_. I'm about to go to lunch. If we're lucky, maybe the OP will have clarified the question by the time I'm back.

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks for your answer, just one thing, can we have a loop for the array in bash? because we might have multiple value and "--conf" need to repeat for each. Also  I was thinking is there any other option except using array?

Comment: Charles's comment shows adding conf options to the array in a loop.

Comment: Other approaches: be careful of https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @Amir, my example in the comment above shows you how to have the code add `--conf` every time it appends to the array.